# Blinking a light in a SAS disk enclosure in Windows using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a supermicro chassis hooked up to a Windows box connected to a generic SAS card.  I find that I can identify the drive in a chassis (eg. blink it's light) using the following PowerShell commands:

1. `Get-Disk | Select number, uniqueid | Where-Object number -eq 29`
2. `Enable-PhysicalDiskIndication -UniqueID  XXX`

Where 29 is the disk number and XXX is the UniqueID returned by 1)

Is there a way to directly pipe the result of 1) (eg., the UniqueID) into 2) so I can accomplish above in a single line?

Thanks!

Comment: See what objects `Enable-Physcial...` takes in. You could just be able to pipe the value of `Get-Disk` after selecting a single property

Comment: Try `Get-Disk -Number 29 | Enable-PhysicalDiskIndication` if that doesn't work try using `Get-PhysicalDisk -DeviceNumber 29 | Enable-PhysicalDiskIndication`.

Comment: You can directly pipe the results of `Get-PhysicalDisk`, a better alternative to `Get-Disk` imo, into `Enable-PhysicalDiskIndication`. You can also pipe `Get-Disk` into `Get-PhysicalDisk` and `Get-Disk` into `Enable-PhysicalDiskIndication`

Comment: Awesome!  That works!  And the LED can be turned off with  Disable-PhysicalDiskIndication.  Does anyone know how to check and see if a particular drive's LED is already blinking?  I don't see a cmdlet to do that and I think it can be done since in Storage Spaces, there is the ability to toggle the LED.  Also what is the difference between "Enable-PhysicalDiskIdentification" and "Enable-PhysicalDiskIndication"?  Thank you!